# How can I modify the price before it is returned from the model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, ruby-on-rails-4

In Ruby on Rails (v4) I want to be able to discount the price via a method in the model. I have `Tags` with rules that are applied to `product`. For example, if a `product` has two `tags` and one says to discount the product $10 and the second rule says to discount the product $3, I need to be able to set the price for the product to the lower of the two rules.

So my question is: Can I override the `@product.price` method with a custom method that will allow me to apply my `Tag` rules first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. Since price is an attribute (I'm assuming), you can always redefine price within the `Product` class.

An example:

```
def price
  calculate_discount
end
```

Then in `calculate_discount`:

```
def calculate_discount
  old_price = read_attribute(:price)
  # apply your rules here
end
```

Comment: It seems to error when I do something like self.price = self.price - 10.00

Comment: Yeah. That's because ruby is assuming you are calling the method `price`. You'll need to explicitly use `read_attribute(:price)`. Please see the updated answer. So you probably need `self.price = read_attribute(:price) - 10.00`.

Comment: That was it. the read_attribute method. Here is the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html) in case someone else comes across the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely can. You can use `before_save` or `after_save` or anything like that to perform the discounting as soon as the `@product` is saved. Something like this might help:

```
def get_tags_and_discount
  self.tags.each do |tag|
    self.price = self.price - tag.discount
  end
end
```